# SQL Script to create Sub directories if they do not exist

Tags: sql, t-sql

Below I have a test script to back up databases not excluded. I need to check if these directories exists in this path first then create them if they do not exist. Then the backup path would need to back up each file into its respective directory. I am kind of lost on how to do this, and per our environmental requirements I cannot use SSMS Maintenance Plan for this job. Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

```
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name  
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files  
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup  
DECLARE @fileDate VARCHAR(20) -- used for file name
DECLARE @Datapath varchar(500)
DECLARE @DirTree TABLE (subdirectory nvarchar(255), depth INT)



-- specify database backup directory
SET @path = '\\nas01\Admin\bbelden\test\' 
SET @Datapath = '\\nas01\Admin\bbelden\test\' + @name

-- specify filename format
SELECT @fileDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) 

INSERT INTO @DirTree(subdirectory, depth)
EXEC master.sys.xp_dirtree @Path

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @DirTree WHERE subdirectory = @Name)
EXEC master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @DataPath

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master',
                    'model',
                    'msdb',
                    'tempdb',
                    'PracticaSd-Dallasmetro')  -- exclude these databases



OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
       SET @fileName = @path + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.BAK'  
       BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName WITH COMPRESSION


       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   



CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = @FileName
```

Comment: Warning: Undocumented procedures ahead: [SQL Server Script to Create Windows Directories](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1460/sql-server-script-to-create-windows-directories/)

Comment: I edited the script, but I am still not able to create the Directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is the answer portion*

Creating a directory that already exists doesn't error or remove files, so go ahead and create it every loop regardless. You wont loose any backups, all happy.

```
declare 
     @dirPath varchar(1024) 
    ,@msg varchar(1024) 
    ,@bkUp varchar(1024) 
    ,@fileDate VARCHAR(20) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),GETDATE(),112) 
    ,@name VARCHAR(128) -- database name  128 is max for sql objects

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT name 
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
WHERE name NOT IN ('master',
                    'model',
                    'msdb',
                    'tempdb',
                    'PracticaSd-Dallasmetro')  -- exclude these databases

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
        set @dirPath = '\\nas01\Admin\bbelden\test\' + @name
        --set @dirPath = 'D:\SQL Server\MSSQL\Backup\' + @name --my home path
        begin try
            exec xp_create_subdir @dirPath;
            set @msg = 'Created directory: ' + @dirPath
            raiserror(@msg,0,0);
            set @bkUp = 'backup database ' + quotename(@name) + ' to disk = ''' + @dirPath + '\' + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.bak'' with compression';
            exec(@bkUp);
            set @bkUp = 'RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = ''' + @dirPath + '\' + @name + '_' + @fileDate + '.bak''';
            exec(@bkUp);
        end try
        begin catch
            set @msg = 'something went wrong!!! with: ' + @name + '    ' + error_message()
            raiserror(@msg,0,0);
        end catch
       FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

*This is more of a comment w/some script.*

Also, be aware that the user attempting to access/create files or folders is the service account.

to check/verify you can

```
sp_configure 'advanced',1;
reconfigure;
GO
sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
reconfigure;
GO
xp_cmdshell 'echo %USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%';
```

and like the previous first comment there are many undocumented stored procedures for file system operations.

- xp_delete_file
- xp_dirtree
- xp_fileexist
- xp_fixeddrives
- xp_subdirs
- xp_create_subdir

Comment: The location is a NAS unit which allow guests full control of this folder. The following command will create a directory: EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_create_subdir '\\nas01\admin\bbelden\test\test1'. I just do not know how to make it create one for each database I am backing up.

Comment: @bbelden What seems to be the problem? You already iterate though each DB you want to back up. Execute the master.sys.xp_dirtree SP for each one.

Comment: I apologize. TSQL scripting is not my strongest area. I am just not sure how to create these directories for each DB on the NAS unit.

Comment: added a working script, try, should fit your stated goals.

Comment: Thank you this does work for creating the directory as you specified. There is one error I am running into now though. Below is the following error:                                                            Created directory: \\nas01\Admin\bbelden\test\ATL-OctopusDeploy
something went wrong!!! with: ATL-OctopusDeploy    Incorrect syntax near '-'.  The directory will be created, but for some reason it seems to not like the hyphen between the two words.

Comment: ok, heh, having a database with - in the name I did not expect, fixed with quotename() around the backup database quotename(@name) which will change it to "backup database [ATL-OctopusDeploy]" so it understands what's between the [] is all one name.